# 1.week.ago.in_zone(Time.zone) for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to use those fancy time helper methods in specific time zones without doing this?

```
Time.use_zone(Time.zone.name) { 1.week.ago }
```

What class(es) should I add a `in_zone` method to so I can do the following without causing too much confusion?

```
1.week.ago.in_zone(Time.zone.name)
```

Or is this already built in?  I'm wondering because I use `Time.zone.now` everywhere and would like a simpler way of doing it on those other cases.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rails has a method called [`in_time_zone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-in_time_zone) which does this for you. It works on any `Time`, `Date` or `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object..

```
1.week.ago.in_time_zone("Tokyo")
```

You can get a list of all the available time zones by running:

```
rake time:zones:all
```

Comment: Rails 4.2 uses the currently set timezone for in the [`ago` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb#L53-L55). Same with [Rails 5.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb#L55-L57).

Comment: I would do as indicated above

```1.week.ago.in_time_zone(Time.zone.name)```

```Fri, 20 Sep 2019 07:39:04 PDT -07:00 ```