# TimeWithZone math loses time zone. Rails 3.2.17 bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, timezone

Rails 3.2.17, Ruby 2.0.0, happens on Heroku, and on my OSX 10.9.2.

After doing math it sets the time zone to the local time zone.

```
date = Time.new Time.zone.now.year, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, '+05:00'
#=> 2014-07-01 00:00:00 +05:00

date - 1.year
#=> 2013-07-01 00:00:00 -0700
#                        ^ Booo, timezone is now local to host machine
```

So I create time in a timezone, all is well. I try to get the exact same time, one year previous and suddenly I'm in my local timezone. This doesn't seem right.

How can I do math on a `TimeWithZone` instance without losing the timezone?

Could this have something do to with the local time of the server

Comment: Which Ruby version, Rails version, and OS version? Also, are you using any gems other than Rails or initializers in your Rails app/elsewhere that might be patching Time, etc.?

Comment: Rails 3.2.17, Ruby 2.0.0, happens both on Heroku and my OSX 10.9.2

Comment: Oh crap I take that back... This _only_ happens on Heroku, and _not_ on my mac. What the hell...

Comment: Actually I take back that takeback... It sets the timezone to the zone local to the host machine, regardless of original time zone.

Comment: Updated (replaced) my answer below now that I understand a little better.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to offset your Heroku timezone with:

```
heroku config:add TZ=America/Los_Angeles
```

Then run Time.now again.

**Update:**

Also this works too

adding following to application.rb works

```
 config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
 config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

Comment: Not the _real_ solution here, but a very useful thing I did not know!

Answer (score 0):

One way is `use_zone`, which allows you to specify a block within which you are using the defined zone:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.4)
2.1.1 :001 > date = Time.new Time.zone.now.year, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, '+05:00'
 => 2014-07-01 00:00:00 +0500 
2.1.1 :002 > Time.use_zone(date.zone) { date - 1.year }
 => 2013-07-01 00:00:00 +0500
```

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380250/1-week-ago-in-zonetime-zone-for-rails) about using the `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` produced by `1.year.ago`, but a duration of time like `1.year` is a `Float` cannot have a timezone associated with it afaik, so working inside the block might be easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out what was going on. `Time.new` (obviously in hindsight) does not create a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` instance. So if I simply convert a `Time` via `in_time_zone` it all works as I expect.

```
date = Time.new(Time.zone.now.year, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, Time.zone.now.strftime('%:z')).in_time_zone
# Tue, 01 Jul 2014 00:00:00 PDT -07:00

date - 1.year
# Mon, 01 Jul 2013 00:00:00 PDT -07:00
```